# Bad syntax in python list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of xlib elements like this:

```
<Choice ID="91149" Total="21"/>
<Choice ID="91139" Total="14"/>
<Choice ID="91159" Total="58"/>
```

I want to pick the element with ID = 91149. In .NET, I could do something like

```
element91149 = (from p in choices where p.id=91149).first
```

I am trying at the syntax in python, working from [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) example from the python tutorial...

```
#example from documentation = x for x in 'abracadabra' if x not in 'abc'
```

My implementation:

```
h = x for x in results if x.get("ID")=="91149" #invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to pick only one such item? If yes, then don't use a LC.

Comment: This is probably not the right way to do this in Python. Generally you wouldn't use list comprehensions unless you're trying to get a list. If you wanted to get all the "91000" IDs, for example, you might do `[result for result in results if "91000"<= result.get("ID") <= "91999"]"`

Comment: @adsmith what is the construct I should use to pick one element called? Just want to know so I can google it.

Comment: @akh2103 You can use `next(x for x in results if x.get("ID")=="91149")`, i.e `next` with a generator expression.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Hardly faster than `[x for x in results if x.get("ID") == "91149"][0]`. I went looking for something we could use e.g. `operator.itemgetter` but it doesn't seem like it exists. Unpacking the one-liner into a for loop may be quicker, and for repeated calls sorting the list by `key=lambda x: x.get("ID")` and doing a binary search will almost DEFINITELY be faster, but just for one grab, I think either `next(generator)` or `[listcomp][0]` are equivalently fast.

Comment: @adsmith The main difference between `next(generator)` and `[listcomp][0]` is that the former will stop at the point where an item with ID="91149" is found, OTOH the LC will iterate over the full `results` no matter what. So, far huge lists the performance difference can be huge.

Comment: @adsmith: depends.  genexps do tend to have a little more overhead, but since `next` can short-circuit it could be very much faster than the listcomp.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Good to know. I assumed both methods iterated over the whole list to begin with, and the generator simply returned one value at a time while the list comp threw the whole thing at you at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) must be enclosed by square brackets `[...]`:

```
h = [x for x in results if x.get("ID")=="91149"]
```

Just for the record, using normal parenthesis `(...)` will create a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
h = (x for x in results if x.get("ID")=="91149")
```

---

However, as @Ashwini mentioned, it is generally very inefficient to read a whole list into memory when all you want is the first item that meets a condition.

Instead, it is usually much faster to use [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) and a generator expression:

```
h = next(x for x in results if x.get("ID")=="91149")
```

Unlike the list comp. (which does it all at once), this solution will yield the items one at a time.  Moreover, it will stop once it finds an item that meets the condition.

Be warned though that it will also raise a `StopIteration` error if it cannot find the item.  To avoid this, you can give `next` a default value to return:

```
h = next((x for x in results if x.get("ID")=="91149"), None)
```

In this case, `h` will be assigned to `None` if an item that meets the condition cannot be found.

Comment: It's nice to see the easy solutions :)